# Which sequence of PDF operators are needed to set the background color of Tf and TF contents?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I need to manipulate the content streams of a page in such a way that if the contents of Tf of one of the elements of TF matches specific values the background area of those squares/glyphs needs to change.

I think that I would need save the graphics state, after creating two different string objects, then apply a fill operator then restore the graphics state.

My question is: would the fill operator recognize the area of the matched string and fill just this?

Second: would I need to repeat this sequence for each element of the TF array?

Comment: It's not quite that simple. You have to determine the position of the text yourself (by keeping track of the current transformation matrix for the whole page content stream and the text matrix for the text object in which your text in question is drawn) and then insert a path outlining that area and filling it just *before* the text object in question.

Comment: That was my suspicion. And the matrices in question I need to look ate are from the new page that is receiving the operators one at a time. Is this correct? Thanks!

Comment: As your additions don't need to change those matrices, the matrix values on the original and the manipulated pages should coincide at corresponding instructions. Thus, you should be able to determine them either on the original page or the result page.

Comment: You are correct. Splitting the strings does not really change any coordinates. Thanks a lot for your help! If you want to put this in an answer, I would be glad accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite that simple.

You have to determine the position of the text *yourself* (by keeping track of the current transformation matrix for the whole page content stream and the text matrix for the text object in which your text in question is drawn) and then insert a path outlining that area and filling it just before the text object in question.

But this in particular means that it is *not necessary* to split the strings of the text drawing instructions to have the search text be drawn by itself.

By the way, if this change of background is meant to represent something like a text marker marking, an alternative to changing the page content would be to create text markup annotations for the determined coordinates. That way you would merely have to *parse* the page content stream for the coordinates, you don't have to *change* it. In particular if the text drawing instructions may also be in some form Xobject referenced from the page content instead of the page content itself, this may simplify the code.